# IP address instead of a domain name in node.js Request module

Tags: node.js, request, ip

Is there any way to use an IP address instead of a domain name in node.js Request module?

I am getting the following error:
[Error: Invalid URI "192.168.0.101/relay1/on"]

I know I shouldn't include the url scheme (e.g: http), so http:// 192.168.0.101/relay1/on wouldn't work either.

Below is the code generating the error:

```
  var arduinoRequestURL = arduinoIp + '/' + modulePrivateName + '/' + req.params.action;
  request(arduinoRequestURL, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
      console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
  });
```

And here is a link to the module:
https://github.com/mikeal/request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Also you must specify the protocol for request.

```
request('google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
      console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
});
```

gives [Error: Invalid URI "google.com"]

The following are equivalent:

```
request('http://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
      console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
});
request('http://74.125.236.18', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
      console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: How would you explain the following error when I add http to my URL: { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }

Comment: URL is defined as: var arduinoRequestURL = 'http://' + arduinoIp + '/' + modulePrivateName + '/' + req.params.action;

Comment: Actually it may just be that my destination is timing out.